# Erdős's exercise.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I have tried to solve an exercise I saw in "Topics in the theory of numbers" (Erdős & Suranyi)
many times but failed every time I tried.

**Here it is:**

Prove that if $a_1,a_2,\cdots$ is an infinite sequence whose elements are either $1$ or $-1$, then for every positive $K$, there exist numbers $b,c,d$ for which $$\left |\sum\limits_{i=k}^d a_{ib+c}\right|>K$$
But I read today that a very similar problem is open. [Look at this abstract.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.2184.pdf)

So, Erdős  suggested as an exercise an open problem?
Or if not can anybody give me a proof of the above statement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should that be $\sum_{k=i}^d$? If so, what's $i$?

Comment: Do you mean$$\left |\sum\limits_{i=k}^d a_{bi+c}\right|>k$$ That is $K$ and $k$ are the same?

Comment: Anyway, the difference between the open problem and the exercise is that in the open problem you are summing along multiples of something, whereas in the exercise you are summing along any arithmetic progression. Presumably, the extra freedom in the exercise makes it an exercise, and not an open problem.

Comment: On a lighter noter: If you solve the conjecture, you surely would have solved this problem

Comment: @GerryMyerson there is a typo in the book.Obviously it is exactly as Yiorgos S. Smyrlis suggests.But does it make such a difference that we are summing multiples?I really doubt.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis no $k$ and $K$ are not the same.

Comment: In the open problem, you can sum along $3,6,9,12,\dots$. In the exercise, you can also sum along $2,5,8,11,\dots$, or along $1,4,7,10,\dots$. That's a lot of extra sums, and I would not be at all surprised if it made a difference.

Comment: It looks like a direct consequence of the Van der Waerden's theorem to me, if I interpreted the problem correctly...

Comment: @DongRyulKim yes but in the book he just mentions V.d.W. theorem.I suppose he does not expect to use V.d.Waerden's theorem.And the exercise does not even have an asterisk which means that it is not difficult to solve.

Comment: By @YiorgosS.Smyrlis' comment, perhaps $k$ should be a parameter (with $b$ $c$, $d$).

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas, the book calls it a "simple application of Van der Waerden's theorem".  The point might very well be that it is hard to prove without Van der Waerden theorem or the more complicated arguments from discrepancy theory.  Assuming "it" is the statement that discrepancy of arithmetic progressions in [1,n] is unbounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from a theorem of Roth. You can read his proof at [1].

He shows not only that it grows unbounded, but we can get a lower bound on the order of growth. Roughly speaking, we can guarantee discrepancy on the order of $O(n^{1/4})$.

The Erdos Discrepancy problem, which is the open conjecture mentioned in a paper you linked to, is the 5th [polymath project](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=The_Erd%C5%91s_discrepancy_problem), so some information is available there. In particular, there is an explicit [solution to the problem you ask](http://gowers.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/rothdiscrepancy2.pdf) written by Tim Gowers.

---

References

[1]: Roth, K. F., Remark concerning integer sequences. Acta Arith. 9 1964 257--260. MR0168545 (29 #5806)

Answer (score 3):

It is exercise 12 of chapter 6.19, where the problem is given as a "simple and interesting application of [Van der Waerden's theorem on arithmetic progressions]".

http://books.google.com/books?id=MTefj5-5OwEC&pg=PA198

There is a typo in the book's statement of the exercise that makes it ill-formed.  Probably the idea is to use Van der Waerden's theorem to prove that discrepancy of arithmetic progressions in $\lbrace 1,\dots, n \rbrace$ is unbounded as a function of $n$.   This is, as they say, a simple application because for large $n$ either the set of $+1$'s or the set of $-1$'s contains (by VdW) an arithmetic progression of length greater than $K$.